# How to change column names where scale() prevents it

Tags: r, scale, names

I think this might be a relatively straight forward answer, but I have no idea where the issue comes from or how to search it. Not that I haven't tried!

In any case, I think it would be nice to have a clear answer for this on SO as I can't be the only person to ever come across this

I have a list of data frames created from tidy which was transposed to give a column for each variable and a row for each of the parameters such as coefficient, confidence intervals etc looks like this:

```
> print(dd)
[[1]]
  Seasonmasika Seasonvuli Parameter
1        -1.35      -0.83  estimate
2         0.25       0.23 std.error
3        -5.51      -3.61 statistic
4         0.00       0.00   p.value
5         0.48       0.45        CI

[[2]]
  scale(Group2) scale(Group3) scale(dist.water) Parameter
1          0.11         -0.46             -0.49  estimate
2          0.08          0.15              0.09 std.error
3          1.40         -3.13             -5.30 statistic
4          0.16          0.00              0.00   p.value
5          0.15          0.29              0.18        CI


> lapply(dd, names)
[[1]]
[1] "Seasonmasika" "Seasonvuli"   "Parameter"   

[[2]]
[1] "scale(Group2)"     "scale(Group3)"     "scale(dist.water)" "Parameter"
```

The problem is the names of the variables are not intuitive and where I scaled the variables in the model, the variable name still has the "scale()" text around it. The worst part is this part of the column name string can't be replaced, only the text inside the brackets. For example this command does nothing to the column names that have scale() in them but works on the others

```
> test<-lapply(dd, function(x){
+   colnames(x)<- gsub(pattern = "Seasonvuli", replacement = "SR", colnames(x))  
+   colnames(x)<- gsub(pattern = "Seasonmasika", replacement = "LR", colnames(x))
+   colnames(x)<- gsub(pattern = "scale(Group2)", replacement = "Acacia-Merua", colnames(x))
+   colnames(x)<- gsub(pattern = "scale(Group3)", replacement = "Combretum-Amarula", colnames(x))
+   return(x)
+ })
> 
> lapply(test, names)
[[1]]
[1] "LR"        "SR"        "Parameter"

[[2]]
[1] "scale(Group2)"     "scale(Group3)"     "scale(dist.water)" "Parameter"
```

But it will replace what is inside the scale() parentheses:

```
> test<-lapply(dd, function(x){
+   colnames(x)<- gsub(pattern = "Seasonvuli", replacement = "SR", colnames(x))  
+   colnames(x)<- gsub(pattern = "Seasonmasika", replacement = "LR", colnames(x))
+   colnames(x)<- gsub(pattern = "Group2", replacement = "Acacia-Merua", colnames(x))
+   colnames(x)<- gsub(pattern = "scale(Group3)", replacement = "Combretum-Amarula", colnames(x))
+   return(x)
+ })
> 
> lapply(test, names)
[[1]]
[1] "LR"        "SR"        "Parameter"

[[2]]
[1] "scale(Acacia-Merua)" "scale(Group3)"       "scale(dist.water)"   "Parameter"
```

Does anyone know why this is occurring and a possible solution to rename these columns as per my first code attempt at the top in the "conventional sense" that this would normally be done?

Comment: Try `pattern = "scale\\(Group3\\)"` ; `)` has a specific meaning in Reg Ex so we need to skip using \\

Comment: I have answered the question accrediting your comment, I suspected it was something tacit like this

Answer (score 1):

This is not my answer but comes from the comment @A.Suliman. It wasn't an issue with scale() as such but with how I was coding the pattern due to the special meaning in Reg ex for parentheses as pointed out in the comment above. So the solution is to code as such

```
> test<-lapply(dd, function(x){
+   colnames(x)<- gsub(pattern = "Seasonvuli", replacement = "SR", colnames(x))  
+   colnames(x)<- gsub(pattern = "Seasonmasika", replacement = "LR", colnames(x))
+   colnames(x)<- gsub(pattern = "scale\\(Group2\\)", replacement = "Acacia-Merua", colnames(x))
+   colnames(x)<- gsub(pattern = "scale\\(Group3\\)", replacement = "Combretum-Amarula", colnames(x))
+   return(x)
+ })
```